# Es posible usar un import dentro de condicional. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-import

> Cita en bloque

Es posible hacer esto

```
theme ? import './styles/ocuro.scss'
: import './styles/claro.scss'
```

O como le hago?

Answer (score 1):

Podes importar modulos dinamicanemten:

```
let mod= (condicion) ? './styles/ocuro.scss' : './styles/claro.scss';
import(mod)
        .then(( res ) => {
            
        })
        .catch( error => {
            // error
        });
```

Saludos.

Aclaro que funciona a partir de ES2020.

Comment: No me funciona, en consola me sale                                                                                                 Error: Cannot find module './styles/ocuro.scss'
    at src|lazy|groupOptions: {}|namespace object:5:1

Comment: Estas pasando bien la rutas? A mi me funciona ok.

Comment: si, si pongo import('./styles/ocuro.scss') si me funciona, pero si pongo import(mod), no

Comment: Podes actualizar el codigo para ver como te quedo? Y si no es confidencial, podes mandar un print del arbol de directorios de la app.